# Upload pic from another website using django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to make an image uploader using images links on the internet (eq: `wwww.google.com/image.jpg`). The user writes the previous url and then my model upload it.

This my code:

*form*

```
<input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" maxlength="255" value="www.example.com/main.jpg"  />
```

*view.py*

```
def Post_date():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Addamazon()
        image_url = request.POST.get('image')
        file = urllib.urlopen(image_url)
        im = cStringIO.StringIO(file.read()) # constructs a StringIO holding the image
        img = Image.open(im)
        save = '/tmp/' + str(int(time.time())) + '.gif'

        img.save(save)
        form.image=save


    if form.is_valid():               
        pic = form.save(commit=False)
        pic.save()
```

*models.py*

```
class Pic(models.Model):
    image = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to='images', sizes=((128, 128),))
```

The image uploads but `if form.is_valid():` doesn't work and I don't know how to add it to the form data.
how i can assign the downloaded image to my form (form.image=save)?

Answer (score 0):

What are you taking from the user input? Is it Image file or the image URL?

If it is image URL then, make the field a forms.URLField and do the post and save like you are doing now.

If it is a image file, then don't extract the image file from the POST request. After you take out the file, (via `read()`) `form.is_valid` fails because that field isn't present. Just do the `form.save()` and the uploading to the right folder with right name, is taken care, for you.

Comment: how i can assign the downloaded image to my form (form.image=save)?

Comment: You should probably give it an "unread blob" in a /tmp. But if you need the URL, why would you want to use a FileField.

Comment: problem solved ,, i have defined another var that content the url of the page ,, then it save the url to database

Answer (score 0):

Do not assign the binary image back to form.image. Instead, add a separate field on the model to store the content of the image, such as a FileField or ImageField, and then after checking if form.is_valid() you can do:

```
def Post_date():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Addamazon()
        image_url = request.POST.get('image')
        file = urllib.urlopen(image_url)
        data = cStringIO.StringIO(file.read())
        name = str(int(time.time())) + '.gif'

    if form.is_valid():               
        pic = form.save(commit=False)
        pic.image.save(name, data)
        pic.save()
```